# Combine group by and Window function

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to combine a window function with a group by for the following function. Given the following table:

```
Table a
ID1   ID2   Value1   Value2
1     1     2        2
1     1     3        2
1     1     2        4
1     2     1        2
```

Here, I first want to calculate value3, which is sum(value2)*sum(value2) for each combination of ID1 and ID2, so as follows:

```
Table a
ID1   ID2   Value1   Value2    Value3
1     1     2        2         64
1     1     3        2         64
1     1     2        4         64
1     2     1        2         4
```

and then group by ID1 to calculate the result sum(value1*value3), so e.g.

```
Result
ID1       Result
1         452
```

I started trying to implemented this query here (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9da0cf/6) but could not find a correct solution.

Is it somehow possible to calculate this in one query without a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
select id1, sum(val1 * val3)
from (select t.*,
             sum(val2) over (partition by id1, id2) * sum(val2) over (partition by id1, id2) as val3
      from t
     ) t
group by id1;
```

Note:  You can use `power()` rather than the "self" multiplication.

Comment: Is it also possible to solve that without a separate subselect?

Comment: @bublitz . . . I can't think of a simple solution without a subquery.